# Identify the type of the grammar

Tags: compilers

I have found the following question from internet. They have even given the answer as option c. But i am confused because the grammar also does not looks like a Regular. Please help me to understand this answer

[image: Qn]

Answer (score 0):

The *given* grammar is context free, non-regular; but they ask for the grammar after eliminating left recursion (by whatever technique they teach to do so).